# Jquery set attribute on appended item

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user clicks on another's name a pop up will show up with a form to send a message to that user. I want to be able to change the attribute 'action' to reflect 'http://localhost:8000/newMsg/'+ user_id; What I have so far changes the form's action but is also changing the other forms too. I know i can use $(this) in certain situations or children() or closest(). But i need to pass the user_id value down from the .chat_list to the specific form. Here is what I have:

**HTML**

```
            <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                            <div class = "contacts_slideout">
                                <div class = "contact_content">
                                    <div id = "chat-box">
                                        <div class = "menteeList">

                                            <div id = "mntList">
                                                 <ul class = "sidebar-nav">
                                                    <li><h1>My Mentee</h1></li>
                                                    @foreach($menteeList as $mentee)
                                                        <li class = "chat_list" value = "{{$mentee->id}}"><div class = "pic_id"></div><a>{{$mentee->name}}</a></li>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
        <div class = "dock">
            <div class = "docking_tabs">

            </div>
        </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.chat_list').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('activated')){
        return false;
    } else {
        var user_id = $(this).attr('value');
        $(this).addClass('activated');
        var el = $(
            '<div class = "message_block">'+
                '<div class = "message_tab">'+ '</div>' +

                '<div class = "message_flyout">' +
                    '<div class = "message_content">' +
                        '<div class = "message_header">'+ '</div>' +
                            '<div class = "conversation_scroll">' +
                                '<div class = "scroll_content">' + '</div>' + '</div>' +
                                    '<div class = "message_form">' +
                                        "<form class = 'myForm' method= 'POST' accept-charset= 'UTF-8'>" + "<input name='_token' type='hidden' value='2rS54FJZJZhWPplLmBJSH4CsID7Pgec7iPsDtrnm'>" +
                                        '<div class = "message_form">' +
                                            "<input class='input-mini' placeholder='Type a message...' name='status' type='text'>" +
                                        '</div>'+
                                        "</form>" +
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                    '</div>');

        $('.docking_tabs').append(el);
        $(".myForm").attr('action', 'http://localhost:8000/newMsg/' + user_id);
    }

});
```

How can I do this properly? Just a side question, would this method be vulnerable for manipulation or hacking?

Comment: For security you need to make sure the data of the post content is sanitized.

Comment: and what is the relation between .chat_list , .docking_tabs and .myForm?? .. you have to provide html .. and I wondered .. why you need to set action for form after append while you can set action <form action= 'http://localhost:8000/newMsg/' + user_i+'"  directly before append

Comment: Mybad i was in a rush

Comment: Change `<form`     to:     `<form action='"+user_id+"' ` and delete the last line that changes the form attribute action

Comment: @RensTillmann can you submit this as an answer so i can give you credit? Thanks I was looking up how to use a variable inside of an .append()

Comment: Of course, thanks, glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`<form`

to:

`<form action='"+user_id+"'`

And delete the last line that changes the form attribute action